# Error Primary Key can't be changed but I dont change the primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I'm using RIA Services, Silverlight 5.0 ..

I got this error when I want to update an item using Ria Services

The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

```
    private void SetPolygonRange()
    {
        var context = new ObjectContext();
        var rangeName = PolygonRangeNameComboBox.Text;
        var query = context.GetPolygonRangesByNameQuery(rangeName);
        context.Load(query, UpdatePolygonRange, context);
    }

    private void UpdatePolygonRange(LoadOperation<PolygonRange> lo)
    {
        var range = lo.Entities.First();
        range.Name = "New Name";
        var context = (ObjectContext) lo.UserState;
        context.SubmitChanges();
        Close();
    }
```

PolygonRange is only ID and Name. I don't update the primary key here, but the error tell me that I can't update the primary key.

Previously, it works well (in Windows 8 and SQL Server 2008). Then I update to Windows 10 and SQL Server 2012, and all of updates function is not working anymore. I'm not sure that the OS update have anything to do with the error.

Comment: You can rule out SQL Server from the possible culprits, it's not an error that can be related to the database.

Comment: @spaghettidba Thanks for the hint. Yes I think it's something related with the RIA Services.

**ObjectContext.PolygonRanges.AttachAsModified(currentPolygonRange, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentPolygonRange)); **

the ChangeSet.GetOriginal always return null. Still haven't found what cause this bug.